# VSTO Word addin to convert JSON data to a word document

Tags: c#, json, vsto

I have made a VSTO add-in for word which triggers a c# windows form to get some JSON data from a website.

Now I want to parse the JSON data to the word document.
I read a lot about VTSO but I can't find the right directions to go forward.

Can some body point me at the right direction?

- is VSTO the right tool for my solution ?
  I like the option to have a extra ribbon with a button to activated a C# form with the behavior I like but then how do I parse the JSON data into the active document?

I hope my question is clear otherwise let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say VSTO has almost nothing to do with parsing JSON or generating Word documents. It can help you to integrate your solution into Word as a ribbon button or as a menu item, but it looks that it's not what you are really after :)

Means, it does not help to generate Word documents (and is not required for this). You could consider using Word document generation library like OpenXml SDK and JSON parsing library like JSON.Net for this.

Comment: Your correct VSTO has nothing to do with parsing JSON Data, but I use VSTO to start a windows form in which I pass in the URL from where to get the JSON data.
In that form I then can select which data I want to add in the word document.

That is why i start using VSTO but it is not clear for me how to present the selected JSON data in word.  The JSON part I have allready up & running in my Add-In form i now looking for the next step:

JSON object ID and body I select in my form to show in my word document what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to represent JSON data in word, sorry. Maybe you could use a table or something?